# Why is my lua code not printing on powershell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, lua

Here is the terminal output: [image]

Here is the code (VSC):

```
print("hi world")
```

I'm on a LUA crash course and I'm stuck on this, thanks (VSC terminal won't work either)

Expected result:

- Code prints out "hi world" in the Powershell terminal

Actual result:

- Prints nothing and waits for my next response

My VSCode: [image]

The path is Users > Dbyrn > OneDrive > Documents > Lua, and my main.lua is located there.

Comment: Did you save the file before running it?

Comment: @user Yeah, I saved it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Just to be sure: What is the result of `type main.lua` in your powershell terminal?

Comment: @Markus since they're using PowerShell, I think they're supposed to use `Get-Command` instead of `type`. See [PowerShell equivalent of BASH (etc) 'type' command?](/q/12320682/11107541). Apparantly `type` in PowerShell is analogous instead to `cat` on UNIX. ([source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPE_(DOS_command)))

Comment: @user Yes, I just would like to see the content of `main.lua` to be sure that the file contains the expected code. Similar to your question "Did you save the file before running it?"

Comment: @Markus ah my bad. I assumed were coming from a UNIX perspective and actually wanted to see info about file type.

Comment: @OMNISENTIENCE Also helpful would be the output of `lua53 -v`.